# How to implement animations using react router 4

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm rusing `React Router v4` and I have some difficulties implementing transitions between pages.

I'm using the package `react-addons-css-transition-group` using transitions for showing the animations as the official React Router examples.

Here's my router:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route render={
    ({ location }) => (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        transitionName="fade"
      >
        <Route
          component={LoginView}
          exact
          key="l"
          location={location}
          path="/"
        />

        <Route
          component={UnderConstructionView}
          exact
          key="uc"
          location={location}
          path="/under-construction"
        />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }
  />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now, On the `UnderConstructionView` I have a simple link `<Link to="/">home page</Link>` that takes my tot he `LoginView`, but no animation is showed.

Anyone who can provide some advice why it's not working.
I must be missing something but I don't see it.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should try wrapping the `Route` Components with a `Switch`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route render={
    ({ location }) => (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        transitionName="fade">
          <Switch key={location.key}>
            <Route
              component={LoginView}
              exact
              key="l"
              location={location}
              path="/" />

            <Route
              component={UnderConstructionView}
              exact
              key="uc"
              location={location}
              path="/under-construction" />
          </Switch>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }
  />
</BrowserRouter>
```